# Printing grouped by values

Tags: java

I have written below code to print the Search objects in the groups map. But I am not getting the correct output.

Mycode:

```
Map<Integer, List<Search>> groups = group.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy( w -> w.getId()) );

            System.out.println( groups );
```

Output I get:

```
{
  1=[Models.Search@30269b0d], 
  2=[Models.Search@423e11a8], 
  3=[Models.Search@25e2f879]
}
```

I want my output to print the grouped Search objects. Please help.

Edited:
sample output I want

```
{
 1=[Michael/14/UK/90, Tim/15/UK/91, George/14/UK/98],
 2=[Jan/13/POLAND/92, Anna/15/POLAND/95],
 3=[Helga/14/GERMANY/93, Leon/14/GERMANY/97]
}
```

Comment: can you paste sample output you are excepting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class Search,override toString like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String res=value1+"/"+value2+"/"+...
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the toString() method in Search class and return your custom String based on the fields that you want to have in the output. What you see here is simply the objects reference.

Edit for sake of completeness:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return res=name+"/"+someNumber+"/"+country+"/"+someOtherNumber;
}
```